# ruby insert equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, string

If I have a string like this: `"4589"` I can do this in ruby:

```rb
str.insert(-4,' ')
```

returns: `"4 589"`

Is anything similar possible in javascript, or do I need to write a function using `split`, `splice` and `join`?

Comment: No, there isn't. Yes, you have to.

Comment: @thiebo I don't know why it's downvoted. Ruby has a number of methods for manipulating strings and arrays that JavaScript doesn't have, so you have to do lower-level things to get them done. Ranges, for an example that comes up all the time with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives are immutable, and there aren't any *single methods* that can do what you want except for a regular expression's `.replace`, which is probably too esoteric to be worth using:

```
str.replace(/(?=.{3}$)/, ' ')
```

But there's no need to turn the string into an array to add the space - you can also use `.slice` twice, to take the `4` part, concatenate with the space, and concatenate with another `.slice`.

```js
const str = '4589';
const newStr = str.slice(0, 1) + ' ' + str.slice(1);
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no *single* thing built in that will do it for you, so yes you'll probably want a function, but it doesn't have to be as complicated as `split`, `splice`, and `join`:

```
function insert(str, index, segment) {
    return str.slice(0, index) + segment + str.slice(index);
}
```

(It can't modify the string because strings are immutable in JavaScript. So it returns the new string instead.)

Live Example:

```js
function insert(str, index, segment) {
    return str.slice(0, index) + segment + str.slice(index);
}

console.log(insert("4589", -3, " "));
```

**Note**: In that, I've stuck to standard JavaScript practice where a negative index is calculated by using `length + index` and specifies where to start the operation. So instead of -4 in the example above, I've used -3 to get the result you got with -4 with Ruby. I was surprised to find that [Ruby's `insert`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-insert) does that calculation but then inserts at the result *plus one* (but only if the index is negative). That would be very odd in a JavaScript function, so I haven't done that above. You could, though:

```
function rubyInsert(str, index, segment) {
    if (index < 0) {
        ++index;
    }
    return str.slice(0, index) + segment + str.slice(index);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function rubyInsert(str, index, segment) {
    if (index < 0) {
        ++index;
    }
    return str.slice(0, index) + segment + str.slice(index);
}

console.log(rubyInsert("4589", -4, " "));
```

Comment: a bit mysterious for me too, but no, "-4" was not a typo

Comment: @thiebo - [Sure enough](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-insert), it inserts at index + 1...but only if the index is negative. How...odd...